# View point shading strength slider missing?

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

[image]
[image]

I am following a tutorial, and I have been instructed to reduce the strength of the viewpoint shading. The slider for strength is not there?

Comment: Could you post the video or show a screenshot? Also, is the tutorial using a pre 2.8 Blender build?

Comment: top image is a screenshot from my blender file, bottom screen shot is from the tutorial. tutorial is using a 2.8 build as am I. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Found it! You need to update Blender from 2.80 to 2.81 (I downloaded the old version to check).

Comment: To be honest...I really wish that Blender auto-checked for updates. I switched to using Blender from steam for that reason.

Comment: Great! thanks for your help guys!